# Yet another .htaccess victim

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am sorry if this is a really simple question, but I have not found out how to do it. How the .htaccess file work is something I never understood.

I have the url:

localhost/[multiple different files.php]

And I  want the simple remove the php suffix and add a trail slash.
But I also have some pages where the get parameter i is used, eg:
localhost/profile.php?i=1

Here I want it to be:
localhost/profile/1

So if anyone could help me with this .htaccess-hell, I would be forever thankfull :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?i=$2 [QAS,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [QAS,L]
```

something like that?

---

to test it: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

- type in the first field: http://localhost/profile/1
- copy the code from above inside the big field.
- click "Check now"

works for me :)

Comment: This did not work, this made it so I got an server error :S
Nor the localhost/ (index.php) or localhost/profile.php?i=1 did work

Comment: did you forget the `RewriteEngine On` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @FredrikStorøy added a testcase.